# Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play при пожизненном бане AdSense

Tags: android, google-play

Стоит ли регистрировать учетную запись разработчика Google Play, если ранее меня забанили в AdSense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно, просто ты не сможешь использовать AdMob, зато в приложении можно будет использовать любые другие рекламные сети.

Comment: Именно это я и подозревал